# Hash Alphanumeric string to a 16 Byte Hex String

Tags: hash

I need a hash algorithm that takes a `28 character alphanumeric [a-zA-Z0-9]` string and outputs a `16 Byte Hex` [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Definition).

**Example**: **hash("cVoFfGI0vhfvWD61Hh1QTsmUJRT2") = 2f234454-cf6d-4a0f-adf2-f4911ba9ffa6**

Is there a way to do so using md5 or SHA1?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1 :**
The alphanumeric string has a fixed length of 28 characters.

Answer (score 1):

here a solution in javascript (nodeJS)

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function hash(input) {
    var s = crypto.createHash('md5').update(input).digest("hex");
    return s.substr(0, 8) + '-' + s.substr(8, 4) + '-' + s.substr(12, 4) + '-' + s.substr(16, 4) + '-' + s.substr(20, 12);
}

hash('cVoFfGI0vhfvWD61Hh1QTsmUJRT2');
```